# React state data null for the first time

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am taking 'data' from the api.For the first time when component render it is getting data as null but after some time it is having api data.I am getting data from api but not able to render it due to initial null value.

```
class CallData extends Component {
      componentWillMount() {
        if (this.props.onPageLoad) {
          this.props.onPageLoad();
        }
      }


      render() {
        const {data} = this.props;
        console.log("data of table...");
        console.log({data});
        if (!data.length) {
          return null;
        }

        return(
          <div>
            {console.log(data)};

          </div>
        );

      }
    }


    export default CallData;
```

Comment: What's the question exactly? You're already handling the fact it may be `null` above, so...?

Comment: I want to show api data when my component is rendered

Comment: So...do that. The above will presumably have something useful in `render` instead of `console.log` when the data isn't `null`.

Comment: Can you show, how are you providing the props to this component and your does your data object look like

Comment: @oxy_js, can you provide the code where you are initializing state inside your class-based component, because you are not doing it with this one that you have provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have two good options:

1. Sepcify default props for the component
   https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html#default-prop-values
2. In render method declare a default value for the data: `const {data = {}} = this.props;`

3.

```
return(
      {this.props.data && <div>
        {console.log(data)};
      </div>}
    )
```