# pass object from state as props to child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I am creating weather app with React and I have an api which provides me object

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import WeeklyWeather from './components/WeeklyWeather';
const api = '';
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      weather: {}
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(api)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => this.setState({ weather: data }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <WeeklyWeather day={this.state.weather.daily.data} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

After fetching it, I store data as state.
Finally, I want to pass this.state.weather.daily.data as props to child component, but I received TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Comment: You need to use `setState` to update the initial state (not `this.state.weather = {.......}`). Could you post the relevant code?

Comment: Ok, give me 3 minutes, I will provide full code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    <WeeklyWeather day={this.state.weather.daily.data} />
```

It can be you get the error because before the async request has finished, there is no `this.state.weather.daily` initialized. Quick hack could be something like this:

```
  {   this.state.weather.daily && <WeeklyWeather day={this.state.weather.daily.data} />}
```

This will make sure `WeeklyWeather` is only rendered when `daily` is initialized.

Answer (score 1):

the first render `this.state.weather` isn't initialized yet

follow this thread 
[React state data null for the first time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43715606/react-state-data-null-for-the-first-time)

```
   class App extends Component {
      constructor () {
        super()
        this.state = {
          weather: {}
        }
      }

      componentDidMount () {
        fetch(proxy)
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(data => this.setState({ weather: data }))
      }

      render () {
        return (
          <div className='App'>
            {this.state.weather && (
              <WeeklyWeather day={this.state.weather.daily.data} />
            )}
          </div>
        )
      }
    }
```

Comment: we start down voting now really? Elan Hamburger ,giorgim

Answer (score 1):

You're passing the prop to the child before it exists.

`componentDidMount()` is called once the HTML is bound to the DOM, which means your `render()` has already run. But, of course, your `render()` refers to `this.state.weather.daily.data` which doesn't exist until after `componentDidMount()` completes.

All you have to do is check that the data is loaded before you attempt to use it.

```
<WeeklyWeather day={this.state.weather.daily && this.state.weather.daily.data} />
```